# Jquery widget callback. Getting a function to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, widget, jquery-widgets

**I added a callback to a jquery widget. It will output data in the console but how do I get it to apply something to the data in the page?**

Example...

in my widget options I have made the following available to receive input:

```
 complete        : ''
```

and have added a method to the widget as well:

```
_complete : function(data) {
        if(this.options.complete) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
```

In another method of the widget I make an ajax call and then call use this `_complete` method to fire after the ajax has finished like:

```
self._complete(self.options.complete);
```

So if, when I use the widget, I pass something to the `complete` option like so:

```
complete : function(){$('.gridrow').css('background-color','#FFF');}
```

I will see this output in the console as:

```
function(){$('.gridrow').css('background-color','#FFF');}
```

But what I really want is to actually apply that to the code, so that it changes the gridrow classes background color.

**I can pass in whatever and get it output in the console but how to I actually apply it to the page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to pass in the `complete` function to your `_complete` function, surely you can just test for it and then execute it. The key change is that you must invoke the `complete` function using `()`:

```
_complete : function() {
        if (this.options.complete) {
            this.options.complete(); // execute the input function
        }
    }
```

If you wish to log the result of that function to the console then ensure that `complete` returns a value:

```
complete : function() { return $('.gridrow').css('background-color','#FFF'); }
```

Then:

```
_complete : function() {
        if (this.options.complete) {
            console.log(this.options.complete()); // print the result
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, basically I am trying to create a callback that I can use at various points in the widget (after a few different ajax loads are completed and a grid loaded). Do you have any suggestion of a better way to do this? I thought that I would need a way to pass different functions into the widget and then execute them. So I could call $('.foo').hide() on one thing or $('.bar').hover() on another all through this complete option.

Comment: Well if you are always going to pass the value of `options.complete` as the argument to your `_complete` function there is no need, as you can access that value yourself. In this way you can just change the function stored in `complete` and invoke the `_complete` function and it will call `complete` automatically.

Comment: Doh! Now I see what you mean. OK, cool so you are saying I could do something like complete: $('.foo').hide(); and then use that in my complete function like you do in the first block of code in your answer. Yes?

Comment: Exactly! This is basically what you were doing already I think.

Comment: Although complete has to contain a `function() { ... }` in order for it to be executed, if not it will just contain a value, which `_complete` will then try to invoke (using `()`) and fail.